# How to resize and move component(Label, PictureBox) in runtime on Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Is it possible to resize and move component in run-time using mouse on Qt? If yes, how? Is there any property? Please share tutorial/docs/guide/howtos!

Comment: What do you mean "component" ? You should specify that.

Comment: Are there layouts involved?

Comment: No Layouts involved!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement resize/move behaviour of `Qwidgets`yourself pretty easy by subclassing and overriding

- [`QWidget::mousePressEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent)
- [`QWidget::mouseMoveEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent)
- [`QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseReleaseEvent)

The first one would have to check where on the widget the mouse is and set some bool variable to mark one of the actions. The Move needs to check if the mouse button is pressed and one of the bools is true and the release calls [`setGeometry()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) with a new size or position.